# Pattern filter terminal

Tags: command-line, scripts, text-processing

My last script generated a txt document that includes the first and last 10 lines of the `/etc/passwd` file.
I want to filter the 20 lines to the file by showing me the first 3 words within `*:*:*`: (where `*`=words)

Here is what I was working around and I couldn't get it work:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo "**********************************"
echo "Today is: "$(date "+%d%m%Y")
echo "**********************************"
echo "This are the data that last script generated"
echo "**********************************"
echo
echo $(grep *:*:*: /tmp/test-file)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to use `grep` you can match the first three fields of each line with

```bsh
grep -o '^[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*'
```

This matches the beginning of the line (`^`), then everything except a colon `:` followed by a colon `:` etc. Thanks to the `-o` option, `grep` prints only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, see `man grep`. Here’s an example with the first and last two lines of `/etc/passwd`:

```bsh
$ grep -oh '^[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*' <(head -2 /etc/passwd) <(tail -2 /etc/passwd)
root:x:0
daemon:x:1
timidity:x:122
geoclue:x:123
```

Read more about Basic Regular Expressions (BRE) in use here on https://www.regular-expressions.info/gnu.html.

Answer (score 3):

Since `/etc/passwd` is a list of fields separated by a stable separator (much like [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)), you should utilize commands that can work with them, like [`cut`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) or [`awk`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gawk.1.html) (for more complex operations).

In this case, `cut` is sufficient:

```
cut -d: -f-3
```

Explanation:

- The flag `-d` sets the delimiter (or field separator). We want `:` here.
- The flag `-f` selects fields to print. `-3` means “up to 3<sup>rd</sup> column”.

Example:

```
$ cut -d: -f-3 /etc/passwd | head
root:x:0
daemon:x:1
bin:x:2
sys:x:3
sync:x:4
games:x:5
man:x:6
lp:x:7
mail:x:8
news:x:9
```

By the way, it is superfluous to issue `echo $(command)`. Use the `command` directly.

Comment: +1 hooray for `cut`! If you want exactly what OP wrote it’s `cut -d: -f-3 <(head /etc/passwd) <(tail /etc/passwd)`.

Comment: it was because of echo sry its satisfy my needs, but i prefer the greg one just because I have to use that instead of whatever other one

Comment: @Nutshelino If you are limited to a single command, use its tag in the question. And you should still use `grep` instead of `echo $(grep)`.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
$ awk -F: 'NR<=20 && NF=3' /etc/passwd
root x 0
daemon x 1
bin x 2
sys x 3
sync x 4
games x 5
...
```

- if `NR<=20` (NR=number of the register) and
- ... after setting `NF` to 3 (NF=number of fields)
- ... print it (default action)

Sorry for the sneakiness ☺